# Phone BluetoothService can't keep bluetooth

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, raspberry-pi4, rfcomm

I want use phone bluetooth to connect raspberry pi in RFCOMM to send and read some data, I try searched some answer on the net and this website,but still can't solve my problem.

I use this MainActivity.java program can show already connected bluetooth address on my phone,and I also can connecting now.
https://github.com/Depeshubela/Main/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/try_wearther1/MainActivity.java

Now my function:
MainActivity:get address and send address to next .java

Navigation.java/Weather.java:connect bluetooth(when I push BTC button) and send/read data from raspberry pi

I separate try Navigation.java and Weather.java is functioning normally

But now, if I mix them and set a button want jump to the nother activity, the bluetooth will be disconnected, I try to write service in background, but it doesn't seem to be working properly.(The activity will be crash)

This is my try write service program,use startService():https://github.com/Depeshubela/Main/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/try_wearther1/BLE.java

I hope can jump many time activity and bluetooth not disconnect,can read and send some data to raspberry pi,like my program Navigation.java and Weather.java.

Thank you for your time to read.